# Find a simplified expression without logarithms

Tags: logarithms

If $2^x=3$, find a simplified expression for $\log_2 3^x$ that does not involve logarithms.

I've actually never done logarithms so someone please help me with this.

Comment: The problem as stated doesn't seem to make sense. Perhaps you mean: If $2^x=3$, find a simplified expression for $\log_2 3^x$ ...".

Comment: Since $3x=9/2$, you may simplify $\log_2(9/2)$ to $\log_2(9)-1=2\log_2(3)-1$.